# How to parametrize the radial direction of a sphere?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, parametric

If I have a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$, how can I parametrize a curve in the radial direction of this sphere?

Imagine I want to parametrize the segment $r$ between origin and the point $P(x,y,z)$ in this picture.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTMmy.png)

Comment: I think you need to elaborate more about what curve are you talking about.

Comment: What do you mean by radial direction? Do you mean the equator of the sphere generated by intersecting the sphere with the $xy$-plane?

Comment: @benguin I mean radial direction as $r$ in [this picture](http://www.seos-project.eu/modules/laser-rs/images/coordinates-spherical.png). And parametrize the segment $r$ between origin and the point $P(x,y,z)$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give more information on the nature of the curve. If it is a line segment, then you can use the parametrization:
$$
tP, \quad t\in [0,1]:
$$
when $t=0$, you are clearly at the origin, and when $t=1$, you are precisely at point $P$. For intermediate values of $t$, you are on the line segment between the origin and $P$.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my post with a picture.

Comment: Ok, in this case the above answer should be what you are looking for.